# How to ensure the chain of promises return an object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I have this function that has a chain of promises and I want to return an object:

```
var signIn = function(fb_ID,fb_accessToken) {
console.log("signin!")
var promise = new Parse.Promise();
var TokenStorage = Parse.Object.extend("tokenStorage");
var query = new Parse.Query(TokenStorage);
query.equalTo('facebookID', fb_ID);
query.ascending('createdAt');
var password;
var username;
var output = {};
var user;
// Check if this ID has previously logged in, using the master key
return query.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(tokenData) {

    // Update the accessToken if it is different.
    if (fb_accessToken !== tokenData.get('fb_accessToken')) {
        console.log('1')
        user = tokenData.get('user');
        user.fetch({
          success: function(data) {
              username = data.get('username')
              tokenData.set('fb_accessToken', fb_accessToken);
              /*
              password = new Buffer(24);
              _.times(24, function(i) {
                password.set(i, _.random(0, 255));
                password = password.toString('base64')
              })
              */
              password = (Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10)).toUpperCase();

              user.setPassword(password);
              tokenData.set('password',password)
              console.log('fetch')
              return
          }         

        }).then(function(){
            tokenData.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function(tokenuser) {
                console.log('tokensave')
                user.save();
                return Parse.User.logIn(username, password);
            }).then(function(data) {
                // Return the user object.
                console.log('output return')
                output.success = true
                output.isnewuser = false
                output.username = username;
                output.password = password;
                output.fb_accessToken = fb_accessToken;
                //return Parse.Promise.as(output);
                //promise.resolve(output)
                //return promise
                return output
            });
        })

    } else {
       console.log('2')
        Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
            username = tokenData.get('username');
            password = tokenData.get('password');
            return
        }).then(function(){
            return Parse.User.logIn(username, password)
            .then(function(data) {
                // Return the user object
                output.success = true
                output.isnewuser = false
                output.username = username;
                output.password = password;
                output.fb_accessToken = fb_accessToken;
                console.log('oo'+JSON.stringify(output))
                //return Parse.Promise.as(output);
                //promise.resolve(output)
                return output

            });
        })

    }
})
//return promise
}
```

The function has two if statements and I would like that both will return 'output' object when I call:

```
signIn(fb_ID,fb_accessToken).then(function(data){
                  if (data.success == true) {
                    console.log('inn'+JSON.stringify(data))
                     response.success(data)
                  }
                  else {
                    console.log('errr')
                    response.error(data)
                  }
              })
```

The 'data' object should be the 'output' object inside the SignIn function. Any idea?

Comment: Well, since you have explained to us, what you want to do, I'd propose to do it as a next step.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `return` before `user.fetch` and `tokenData.save` in first `if` block. In the `else` block put `return` before `Parse.promise.as`.

Your current implementation looks like something similar to this.

```
var someFunction = function () {
        return mainPromise().then(function () {
            if (someCondition) {
                somePromiseOne().then(function () {
                    return data;
                });
            }
            else {
                somePromiseTwo().then(function () {
                    return data;
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

In the both cases you should put `return` before `somePromiseOne` and `somePromiseTwo` in order to pass the `data` to the promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do quite a lot to tidy things up ... and get it working.

First, you can (and should) move the code from the `user.fetch({ success:... })` callback into the following then's callback. "Property-style" callbacks should be avoided when a promise interface is available (and already used).

Then, you might aim for flow control as follows :

```
doSomethingAsync().then(function() {
    var promise;
    if(condition) {
        promise = ...; // deliver username and password
    } else {
        promise = ...; // deliver username and password
    }
    return promise.then(function(details) {
        return login().then(function() {
            // fully compose output object here
            return details;
        });
    });
});
```

In practice, the code will be more extensive due to the number of async steps and the volume of synchronous code, particularly in the first condition.

In full, you might end up with something like this :

```
var signIn = function(fb_ID, fb_accessToken) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend('tokenStorage'));
    query.equalTo('facebookID', fb_ID);
    query.ascending('createdAt');
    // Check if this ID has previously logged in, using the master key
    return query.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(tokenData) {
        var promise;
        // Update the accessToken if it is different.
        if (fb_accessToken !== tokenData.get('fb_accessToken')) {
            var user = tokenData.get('user');
            promise = user.fetch().then(function(data) {
                var details = {
                    username: data.get('username'),
                    password: (Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10)).toUpperCase()
                }; 
                tokenData.set('fb_accessToken', fb_accessToken);
                tokenData.set('password', details.password);
                user.setPassword(details.password);

                // Assuming here that `tokenData.save()` and `user.save()` are both async and can be executed in parallel.
                return Parse.Promise.when([
                    tokenData.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }),
                    user.save()
                ]).then(function() {
                    return details;
                });
            });
        } else {
            // here `promise` mimics the final successful state of the promise in the other condition.
            // ie. promise-wrapped details
            promise = Parse.Promise.as({
                username: tokenData.get('username'),
                password: tokenData.get('password')
            });
        }
        return promise.then(function(details) {
            // whichever condition was executed, username and password details are delivered here in an identical format.
            return Parse.User.logIn(details.username, details.password).then(function() {
                details.success = true;
                details.isnewuser = false;
                details.fb_accessToken = fb_accessToken;
                return details; // deliver details to signIn's caller
            });
        });
    });
}
```